# Union of two open paracompact subspaces is paracompact?

Tags: general-topology, paracompactness

> Is the union of two open paracompact subspaces of a space $X$ paracompact?

A space is called [*paracompact*](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000030) if every open cover of the space has a locally finite open refinement.

*Proof attempt*: Suppose $X=O_1\cup O_2$ with each $O_i$ open and paracompact.  Given an open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$, intersect every element of $\mathcal U$ with $O_1$ to get an open cover of $O_1$.  Then take a refinement of that cover that is locally finite in $O_1$.  And similarly for $O_2$.  The union of the two refinements is an open cover of $X$ that refines $\mathcal U$.  But I am having difficulty showing the result is locally finite.

Presumably the union is not paracompact in general.

What would be a (Hausdorff if possible) counterexample?

Comment: If you live in $O_1\cap O_2$, you can use the intersection of neighborhoods witnessing locally finite in each. If you live in $O_1\setminus cl(O_2)$, you can use the neighborhood from $O_1$ subtracting $cl(O_2)$, Likewise for $O_2\setminus cl(O_1)$. So it'd seem the trickiness is when you're on the boundary of $O_1$ or $O_2$?

Comment: Yes, the tricky part is on the boundary of the open sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the so-called *Thomas plank* provides a counter-example:

Let $A(\omega_1) = \omega_1 \cup \{\infty\}$ and
$A(\omega) = \omega \cup \{\infty\}$
be the one-point compactifications of the *discrete* spaces
$\omega_1$ and $\omega$, respectively.

$X := (A(\omega_1) \times A(\omega))  \setminus \{(\infty, \infty)\}$ is completely regular, T2.
It is well-known that $X$ is not even normal
(the closed, disjoint sets $\omega_1 \times \{\infty\}$
and $\{\infty\} \times \omega$ cannot be separated).
In particular, it is not paracompact.

$U := A(\omega_1) \times \omega$ and
$V := \omega_1 \times A(\omega)$
are products of a compact and a discrete space.
Hence, they are paracompact (in fact $U, V$ are hereditarily ultraparacompact).

Of course, $U, V$ are open in $X$ and $U \cup V = X$.

Comment: Very nice example!

Comment: For reference, the space is described in Engelking 2.3.36, where it is shown it is not normal.